# Use HTML5 to make a page with no scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want my page to be displayed in full without the need (or ability) to scroll down. I want to have a footer that will display at the bottom of the screen. I've found so many answers on here and Google that will probably work, but I am a noob and can't make too much sense of them or how to apply the information to my code.

here is my STYLE code:

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'gooddogregular';
        src: url(GoodDog.otf)
    }

    html {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
        text-align: left;
        background-image: url("border.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
    }
    header {
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
    }
    nav {
        width: 950px;
        border: 2px;
    }
    article {
        width: 700px;
        display: table;
        font-family: gooddogregular;
    }
    h1 {
        font-family: gooddogregular;
        font-size: 50px;
    }
</style>
```

My body tag is just a body tag, nothing added to it or anything. Essentially I want the page to not scroll, and all content just rest in the middle (or middle left and middle right).

Maybe a better question would be how do I position elements such as footer, images, articles etc with precision? Anyway to use coordinates that are not based on pixel, such as percent?

I tried adding `height:` to my body style, but no matter what I set the height, it has zero effect.

Comment: Use `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`...

Comment: You are expressing a desire to control how the content is displayed. How should devices with different screen sizes display your content? What about screens with different pixel densities? What about folks who use screen readers instead of browsers?

Answer (score 0):

If you want nothing to happen when you scroll, position the elements with fixed positions like this:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
left: 10%;
```

When you scroll, fixed position elements do not move.

To disable scrolling altogether, use this CSS:

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
}

body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```